# Error R10 when deploying the API using AdonisJS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, adonis.js

Here is the error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Analyzing the log, I noticed that every time I 'run' the app on Heroku it directs to a different port.

I have already encountered numerous examples of how to solve this, but using Express and not explicitly using AdonisJS (which I am finding very limited).

Another issue I have is the use of the domain for my application, should the be the same as the Heroku provides or localhost (127.0.0.1)?

My log:

```
2019-03-28T12:54:19.688098+00:00 app[web.1]: info: serving app on http://127.0.0.1:48470
2019-03-28T12:55:17.075091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-28T12:55:17.081028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-28T12:55:16.883066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-03-28T12:55:16.883174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-03-28T12:55:17.056876+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-03-28T12:55:20.176409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `ENV_SILENT=true npm start`
2019-03-28T12:55:22.553527+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-28T12:55:22.553548+00:00 app[web.1]: > adonis-api-app@4.1.0 start /app
2019-03-28T12:55:22.553551+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-28T12:55:22.553552+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-28T12:55:23.598805+00:00 app[web.1]: info: serving app on http://127.0.0.1:37943
2019-03-28T12:56:20.763929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-28T12:56:20.660053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-03-28T12:56:20.660202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-03-28T12:56:20.747895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-03-28T12:56:23.940320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=***** protocol=https
2019-03-28T13:21:40.085858+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-28T13:21:43.920685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `ENV_SILENT=true npm start`
2019-03-28T13:21:46.419408+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-28T13:21:46.419429+00:00 app[web.1]: > adonis-api-app@4.1.0 start /app
2019-03-28T13:21:46.419431+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-03-28T13:21:46.419433+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-03-28T13:21:47.899057+00:00 app[web.1]: info: serving app on http://127.0.0.1:51104
```

My `.env` file:

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=8080
NODE_ENV=development
APP_NAME=AdonisJs
APP_URL=https://${HOST}:${PORT}
APP_KEY=*******
```

How to prevent the port from being changed?

Comment: Your `.env` file should only be used in development. It's basically a convenience for populating environment variables, but [Heroku uses environment variables for configuration natively](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Is it committed to your repository?

Comment: The .env file is in my repository

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here.

## Configuration from the environment

There are two main benefits to [configuring your application from the environment](https://12factor.net/config):

- It makes configuration environment-specific, e.g. so you can use different databases, mail servers, etc. in development from the ones you use in production
- It lets you keep sensitive values like API keys and passwords out of your codebase

Including your `.env` file in your repository negates both of these benefits. It's fine to use one in development, and it can be a convenient way to set environment variables, but it shouldn't be committed to your repository or used in Heroku.

Heroku [natively supports configuration from the environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You can set variables in the web UI or via `heroku:config` on the command line. This is where your environment variables should go in production.

I *strongly* urge you to remove your `.env` file from your repository with

```
git rm --cached .env
```

add it to your `.gitignore`, and use Heroku's native environment-based configuration instead. You should also invalidate any API keys or passwords that are contained in that file and generate new ones.

For what it's worth, the AdonisJS documentation [agrees with this approach](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/configuration-and-env#_env_provider):

> The `.env` file should never be committed to your source control or shared with other people.

## Different ports

[This is entirely expected](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers):

> On Heroku, apps are completely self-contained and do not rely on runtime injection of a webserver into the execution environment to create a web-facing service. Each web process simply binds to a port, and listens for requests coming in on that port. The [port to bind to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos) is assigned by Heroku as the `PORT` environment variable.

Heroku tells you which port to bind to via the `PORT` environment variable, and you must use it. But this isn't the port that will be visible externally; the standard HTTP ports will be routed to your application automatically.

## IP addresses

Your application should listen on all IP addresses. If you're using Express, I think that means you don't provide an IP address in your `.listen()` call. You should only provide the port there, and that port should come from the `PORT` environment variable.